# What is the name of a drink made with iced tea and orange juice?

Tags: tea, oranges, lemonade

Iced tea and lemonade is known as an Arnold Palmer.  I mix mine in 50/50 proportions.

Lacking lemonade, I mixed 50/50 iced tea and pulpy orange juice.  I really kind of like the result and nicknamed it a "Hairy Palmer" (because the pulp normally suspended in the OJ floats to the top when diluted with tea, making the drink look "hairy").

Is there a legit name for this drink?

Comment: Why "hairy"...?

Comment: Because all the pulp congeals at the top and "fuzzy" seemed to be taken.

Comment: Is there an any more _legit_ name?

Answer (score 5):

Having a citrus juice in iced tea certainly isn't a new concept. However, there is no official name for half orange and half iced tea drinks. So you may call it whatever you wish.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a sunrise, the sell it at roscos

Comment: Welcome to the site - remember its global, and not everyone knows who/what Rosco is.  It may help to show where in the world this phrase is common, by using [edit] to extend your answer.